# Copy failures from AccessDB to Azure DataFactory (through Integration Runtime)

Tags: ms-access, azure-data-factory

I am having trouble copying data from an AccessDB using the copy activity in Azure Data Factory.

The copy sometimes works, and seems to work better after it's "rested" for a bit.

The initial error from the pipeline runs:

```
ErrorCode=UserErrorFailedToConnectOdbcSource,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.GenericOdbcConnectors,''Type=System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException,Message=,Source=,'
```

Going deeper into the IR logs from when this error occurs, there's a bunch of information, but specifically there is also this error in the logs:

```
 TraceComponentId: TransferTask
TraceMessageId: TransferRunFailed
@logId: Error
FunctionName: Execute
jobId: cb6df474-ff8a-13a0-1d17-6e7f3baf5f8e
activityId: 1db37d81-cd32-4b6f-8d16-7fcf63ddea35
eventId: TransferRunFailed
message: Copy failed with error: 'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.GenericOdbcConnectors,StackTrace=   at Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.GenericOdbc.GenericOdbcConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.SourceStageProcessor`1..ctor(PluginRegistration plugins, IDictionary`2 stageProperties, Func`2 hookTelemetry)
   at Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.PipelineDefinitionBuilder.CreateTabularSourceProcessor(IDictionary`2 properties)
   at Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.PipelineProcessStage`3.CreateProcessor(Func`1 createNextProcessor)
   at Microsoft.DataTransfer.TransferTask.CopyTask.DoCopy()
   at Microsoft.DataTransfer.TransferTask.CopyTaskBase.Execute(),''Type=System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException,Message=,Source=,StackTrace=   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle, RetCode retcode)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionOpen..ctor(OdbcConnection outerConnection, OdbcConnectionString connectionOptions)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HelperMethod.ExecuteWithTimeout(Action action, TimeSpan timeout, HybridDeliveryExceptionCode exceptionCode, String errorMessageFormat)
   at Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.RetryPolicies.RetryExtension.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<ExecuteAction>b__0()
   at Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.RetryPolicies.RetryExtension.ExecuteAction[TResult](IRetry retry, Func`1 func)
   at Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.GenericOdbc.GenericOdbcConnection.Open(),'
```

This does sometimes work, it's intermittent, so I'm leaning towards something like a pool size error? However, I'm not sure what to try next - will be logging a support ticket with Microsoft soonest.

Comment: Did you ever figure out this issue? I'm having the same issue. If I restart the IR after my pipeline, everything works but if I try to run the pipeline again without restarting, I get this error.

Comment: Unfortunately not, but thankfully we ended up moving away from requiring this. I'd recommend trying to increase the maxlocks per file as a starter, or copying your AccessDB so that you know it's fresh and no one else can touch it while you test.

Answer (score 0):

Benjamin

Since you mentioned it is working at other times. It needs some cooling of period and needs some time to work again. I am assuming there are multiple people / processes (like the previous adf instance is connected) connected to the db and hitting the the threshold.

The property is called  **MaxLocksPerFile**  - setting limits the file sharing.

If the number is low - you might encounter a similar behavior.

You could increase this number to higher value and check whether that resolves the issue.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1e152f31-3b5e-424b-b6a1-2a1651a909be/how-to-update-the-maxlocksperfile-registry-for-microsoft-access-for-office-365-64bit?forum=Office2016ITPro

Comment: Thanks Satya - we found a workaround that didn't need AccessDB for the time being, so I haven't had to look into this. I remember checking this value and thinking it already seemed high, but if I revisit, this will be my first port of call.